# Wemos D1 and TFT LCD shield

Tags: arduino

I'm using an Arduino-like WeMos D1 and a TFT LCD shield on it. When I want to run a sample program like graphictest, it does not compile the program and it gives me these errors:

```
Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

A3' was not declared in this scope
A2' was not declared in this scope
A1' was not declared in this scope
```

Here is the code for defining pins:

```
#define LCD_CS A3 // Chip Select goes to Analog 3
#define LCD_CD A2 // Command/Data goes to Analog 2
#define LCD_WR A1 // LCD Write goes to Analog 1
#define LCD_RD A0 // LCD Read goes to Analog 0
```

Comment: The defines for the `A3` etc are in https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h, so you need to `#include <pins_arduino.h>` first, or do direct pinnumbers such as 3,2,1 etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the WeMos D1 board, you would see that there is no `A1`, `A2` or `A3` pins.
ESP8266 has only one analog pin (`A0`) and that one can't be used as a digital pin.

[image]

Comment: now how can I define this Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

Comment: You can't use the LCD as a shield. You will need to rewire it to use other pins and then use those pins in code.